# Select-Object -ExcludeProperty based on the property's value

Tags: powershell

I have an object that has a large amount of properties. I want to return several of these properties, whose names may not always be consistent. I want to EXCLUDE properties that have or contain a particular value.

```
$notneeded = @('array of properties that I do not wish to select')
$csvPath = "$Log\$Summary"
$csvData = Get-Content -Path $csvPath | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Csv #the first line is extra (not a header), needs skipped
$csvData | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty $notneeded
```

If the list of properties to exclude was static, then I could use this. But I want to exclude properties from view that contain a particular value.

Comment: Property names to exclude may contain wildcards see `gci -file | select * -excl *name,*time*,ver*,PS*|ft -au`

Comment: If I understand your demand: `$notneeded = ($csvData | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name  | Where-Object {$csvData.$_ -like '*particular value*'}`

Comment: I don't understand one thing, does the CSV have 1 record? If not, do you want to exclude a property if any record has a specific value, or if all records have that value? Do you expect this to be evaluated on a record by record basis?

Comment: @JosefZ - That worked beautifully. Thank you! I can accept it as the preferred answer if you want to submit it as an answer.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Yes, sorry. Just the 1 record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INPUT** CSV

```
John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
,Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298
"Joan ""the bone"", Anne",Jet,"9th, at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$csvData = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header  "Name", "Surname", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip"
$particularValue = "*120*"
$notneeded = @()
$csvData | Foreach-Object { $notneeded += $_.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object Value -like $particularValue | Select-Object Name }
$notneeded = $notneeded | Select-Object -Unique -ExpandProperty Name
$csvData | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty $notneeded | Format-Table
```

Note That e.g. I want to exclude column where 120 is mentioned. Also I named columns in my script

**OUTPUT** (See the address column is missing)

```
Name                  Surname  City        State Zip  
----                  -------  ----        ----- ---  
John                  Doe      Riverside   NJ    08075
Jack                  McGinnis Phila       PA    09119
John "Da Man"         Repici   Riverside   NJ    08075
Stephen               Tyler    SomeTown    SD    91234
                      Blankman SomeTown    SD    00298
Joan "the bone", Anne Jet      Desert City CO    00123
```